# Appropriate code architecture in Kotlin for long running code that updates the android UI on completion

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

*Note: Updated Question code;
Changed code to using Deferred not Job which seems cleaner, though does require use of async rather than launch.
Make it clear I utilise the LiveData class in the ViewModel*

I'm struggling to wrap my head around the recomended approach for error handling in Android with Kotlin when invoking multiple tasks on non Main Dispatchers from another.

What I've got is essentially boiled down to the following code. I use Deferred rather than Job because I can handle the exceptions if I use Deferred rather than Job.

I use LiveData in the ViewModel because this is what tutorials suggest is appropriate for the UI to be dealing with.

**My Question is**: Is the following a sensible approach for Android now with Kotlin? Essentially, I just want to be able to kick long running processes off, then report the success or failure of them on the screen. What have I missed that is causing me to make what should be easy seem so complicated? Many thanks.

In the example code below, I use Hilt injection, and RoomDB. *I'm not using Android compose.*

I've simplified my classes to: MyFragment - MyViewModel - MyViewModelLogic - MyRepository
I've written the code below as an example, I've not run it through a compiler so there might be occasional syntactic errors. I've tried to remove all the non relevant code.

```
// UI creation and update
@AndroidEntryPoint
class myFragment : Fragment() {

    private val myViewModel : MyViewModel by viewModels()

    fun onButtonClick() {
        //TODO start indeterminate a progress bar
        //TODO block user from starting action again
        myViewModel.doTasks().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            if(it.isSucess) {
                doOnTaskSuccess()
            } else {
                doOnTaskFailure(it.error)
            }
            //TODO stop indeterminate progress bar (in main thread if UI still visible)
            //TODO permit user to run this action again
        }
    }
    
    fun doOnTaskSucess() {
        Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.toast_task_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    
    fun doOnTaskFailure(e : Exception) {
        // create and show a helpful message for the User depending on the reason for error
    }
}



// interface between UI and business logic, also contains current state of the UI
@HiltViewModel
class MyViewModel @Inject constructor(private val myViewModelLogic : MyViewModelLogic) : ViewModel() {

    fun doTasks() : LiveData<TaskResult> {
        val output = MutableLiveData<TaskResult>()
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            val result = TaskResult()
            try {
                viewModelLogic.doTasks().await()
                result.isSuccess = true
            } catch(e : Exception) {
                result.error = e
            } finally {
                output.value = result
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}

// a way of capturing task result or error for propogation to UI
class TaskResult {
    var isSuccess : Boolean = false
    var error : Exception?
}



// this is essentially a controller, it contains business logic manipulating data for pushing to the UI, pulling and pushing data to repositories.
class MyViewModelLogic @Inject constructor(val myRepo : MyRepository) {
    @Inject coroutineScope : CoroutineScope
    
    @Throws(IllegalStateException::class)
    suspend fun longRunningSuspendTask() {
        // do some stuff
    }
    
    
    fun doTask2() : Deferred<Unit> {
        return coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            longRunningSuspendTask // can throw IllegalStateException on error
        }
    }
    
    
    fun doTasks() : Deferred<Unit>{
        return coroutineScope.async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            myRepo.doSuspendingTask1()
            doTask2.await() // wait for the task to finish
            // doSomething else
        }
    }
}


class MyRepository @Inject constructor(db : MyDatabase) {
     // suspend because its in a Repository class
    suspend fun doSuspendingTask1() : Job {
        longRunningTask
    }
}
```